# Is it possible to have the cursor follow a newly-created window?

Tags: vim-windows, split

When I split my window (`C-w v`), is it possible to have the cursor automatically go to the new split right away?

(I looked up `switchbuf` but I think that's something else; having to do with buffers rather than windows?)

Comment: `Ctrl-W N` _does_ move the cursor to the newly opened window (where a new buffer exists). `Ctrl-W V` is a slightly different animal. Besides doing vertical split instead of horizontal it uses the same buffer as the one you ran the command from. Under most circumstances it doesn't seem like it matters whether you're in the new window or the current window since the contents are identical. You sure you don't mean the vertical equivalent of `Ctrl-W N`? Just want to be sure.

Comment: @BLayer you're absolutely right. I wrote my question absent-mindedly; it only happens when splitting.. and while it may not technically matter, I find it annoying every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I split my window (C-w v), is it possible to have the cursor automatically go to the new split right away?

In fact, you *do move* to the newly created window. The point is that it's opened on the left side by default.

So you need to `set splitright`. Be aware though, this option affects *all* vertical split commands, not only `:vsplit`.